# How to organize a database of countries and zones for javascript manipulation?

Tags: javascript, xml, database, json

I'm not a programmer, but I've done all the customizations for my web shop myself.  I use zen-cart.  I'm trying to make it more user friendly for international customers and its become apparent that zen-cart is only "international" on a cursory level.  it is very US-centric with some token nods to other "common" countries like Canada, UK, etc.

Anyway, I'm trying to re-do the sign-up sheet so the address is more sensical for any visitor regardless of their country.  So they select the country and the "state" auto-populates... that's built in already (just have to add all the "states" for each country manually to the database) but the problem is the JS gets rather huge.  Further than that, I want to change how the labels are displayed.  ie. "city" should read "municipality" for visitors from Argentina.  An obvious one is "province" for Canada, etc.  But then the JS just gets that much more huge.

You end up with a ginormous series of if statements covering some 260 countries with an average of some 8 to 10 "states" each and then each having its own wording for "street", "suburb", "city", "state" and "postal" labels.

So my question is... can this be efficient?  Can this be "lite"?  Do we really have to populate the client browser with all that data or is there a better way (and still have it be dynamic without extraneous page loads)?

Or is it OK to just have it all piled in there?  On my local server, it loads reasonably quick.  I haven't tried it on a web server and I really don't have a way to test on a "slow" connection so I just want to code it properly from the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: You could load all countries and all states in the client, but that's bad practice. You should only load the data you need. The user selects a country, and that fires off an ajax request to the server to return the respective states. That would be a better way to do it.

Comment: In many cases I would agree with you, but in this case, I think 260 countries is not a large amount of data, especially after being zipped. I expect the ajax request would probably take longer than downloading the data in the first instance. I don't think good/bad practice is that clear cut on this issue - I think it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That amount of data is not huge if you are going to improve the user interface with it.

Your server should be implementing a gzip method to compress the data before being sent to the client, and repetitive data compresses really well.

I expect you should be using a data structure something like this in JSON

```
var countryData = [
  { name: "USA",
    provinceName: "City",
    suburbName: "Suburb"
  },
  { name: "Canada",
    provinceName: "Province",
    suburbName: "Suburb"
  }
]
```

You could keep all that in a separate file to help keep your javascript organized, and use a `script` tag to load it before your main script runs.

Also, to test the performance hit, I would use a tool like YSlow which runs inside the firebug extension for firefox browser. It is made by yahoo, and allows you to see the loading time for all the components of a page, with caching or without, and allows you to examine which files are compressed or not.

Comment: Although your example only covers the label names so I wonder if your "it isn't that big" thinking was missing the state names?  It would be like you say but then ALSO an array of between 1 and 100 "states" each (US has 50, Canada has 13, Spain has a boat load... etc).  Does that change your thinking?  Or still not that much?

Comment: I think it would still be ok, but the test is to create the JSON data including all the data you need (or good dummy data that equally represents it) and then use gzip to compress it. You can judge for yourself then, if it is worth the file-size of the gzipped JSON data file for the functionality you need. I would expect the final file to be in the region of 20K after compression, which is a little bit heavy, but I would not say unfeasible in modern websites which commonly weigh between 150-200K

Comment: And it is a good point about the states, that does change the quantity of data significantly

Comment: Thanks.  And it only comes into play on the signup sheet anyway so its not like its bogging down every page.

Comment: Let me know how big the file is, for my curiosity, and if you feel like it, make it available as a github gist or something so other people can use it in the future... unless there is already one out there... in which case post a link to it here on this question. ,~)